# Why static data members are not part of object in c++?

Tags: c++

I know that static members don't belong to objects.
But why is it so?

And when is the memory for static data members allocated?

Comment: Because they don't? Because that's their purpose? Because that's what `static` members _mean_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that static members don't belong to objects. But why is it so?

Because you use `static` members whenever you have some quantity that all objects 
"share", say for example the number of instances class Foo has. Such a "shared" member cannot belong to a particular instance. When a new `Foo` object is being created, then the static variable `num_instances` is incremented. If the variable wasn't static, then each new Foo will start with a clean state, and couldn't possibly know about other Foo's. Example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    static int num_instances; // all instances share this variable
public:    
    Foo()
    {
        ++num_instances; // increment the number of instances
    }
    static int get_num()
    {
        return num_instances;
    }
};

int Foo::num_instances = 0;

int main()
{
    Foo foo1, foo2;
    std::cout << "We have " << Foo::get_num() << " Foo's" << std::endl;
}
```

> And when is the memory for static data members allocated?

The memory for static objects is allocated before program startup.

Comment: Can you please clarify more about "before program startup" time.

Comment: @WhoAmI: `static` member variables are effectively global variables.

Comment: @WhoAmI that is, before `main()`. I don't know further details, but I do know that the order of initialization is unspecified. That is, if you have two static members in two different classes, it is not guaranteed that one will be initialized before the other (whenever the classes are defined in separate files).